Trying to implement scroll animation in Nextjs14 with tailwindCss and framer motion
I found this nice scroll effect text and I am trying to replicate the same scroll effect on words in Nextjs, TailwindCSS and Framer motion.
This is what my current solution looks like-
"use client";
import { cn } from "@/utils/cn";
import { motion, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const ScrollWords = ({
  src,
  className,
}: {
  src?: string;
  className?: string;
}) => {
  const sentence =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac sapien nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec nunc nec nunc ultricies ultricies. Nullam nec";
  const words = sentence.split(" ");
  const [revealedWords, setRevealedwords] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { scrollY } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const newRevealedWords = Math.floor(scrollY.get() * words2.length);
      setRevealedwords(newRevealedWords);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [scrollY, words]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
      viewport={{ once: true }}
      className={cn(
        "flex flex-wrap justify-center min-h-[200vh] relative items-center",
        className,
      )}
      ref={ref}
    >
      {words.slice(0, revealedWords).map((word, index) => (
        <motion.span
          key={index}
          initial={{ y: 100, opacity: 0 }}
          whileInView={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.8, delay: index * 0.05 }}
          style={{
            opacity: scrollY.get() * (1 / words2.length),
            gridColumn: (index % 5) + 1,
            gridRow: Math.floor(index / 5) + 1,
          }}
          className="text-4xl font-bold text-white mr-2"
        >
          {word}{" "}
        </motion.span>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

I am not using gsap, instead using Framer motion. My code works a little bit but I am unable to have the words appear and the motion.div stay "fixed". I thought, I could use scrollY from useScroll() and track the Y values as you scroll down and as the values increase, using [revealedWords, SetRevealedWords] to display each word for each scroll increment, that is the expected behavior but I am unable to achieve that.
As I scroll, the words do appear but they appear all together in a staggered motion and the div is scrolled up and out of the viewport. How can I have the same animation effect as in the example I provided?
